# POST request to update data fields - AngularJS, Django

Tags: angularjs, django, http-post, httprequest

I have two models:

```
class Lecture(models.Model):
    lecture_no = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True, null=True)
    youtubeLink = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True, null=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, null=True)
    keywords = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True)
    #Could add Next Rerun Date & Time

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Notes(models.Model):
    notes = models.TextField(null=True)
    lecture = models.ForeignKey(Lecture, null=True, related_name='lecture')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.notes
```

These serializers:

```
class NotesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    lecture = LectureSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Notes
        fields = ('id', 'notes', 'lecture')

class KeywordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    lecture = LectureSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Keyword
        fields = ('id', 'notes', 'lecture')
```

and these views:

```
class LectureViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = LectureSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        course_id = self.request.query_params.get('course',False)
        if course_id:
            lectures = Lecture.objects.filter(course=course_id)
        else:
            lectures = Lecture.objects.all()
        return lectures


class NotesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Notes.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NotesSerializer
```

and I'm trying to make it so that I can update the "notes" field for a specific lecture. Currently I'm using a POST http request:

```
saveNotes: function(notes, lecture_id, callback) {
      $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: apiRoute + 'notes/',
        data: {
          "notes": notes,
          "lecture_id": lecture_id
        }
      }).success(callback);
    }
```

But this just adds a new row to the database every time. How do you update fields instead?

Thanks

Comment: Try using a PUT method

Comment: You need to show your views.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've added them to the post. Thanks.